# Execution of Stored Procedure in .NET application using SQLQuery returns incorrect values

Tags: .net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures, prepared-statement

## Issue Descripton:

I am trying to call a stored procedure in a .NET Core application.
For testing purpose I am sending hard coded values with same value and datatype as to what I'm passing in SQL Server query editor.

#### The following is screenshot of what values, Stored Procedure Name and its datatype I am passing in SQL Server query editor:

[image: Expected Values from DB]

#### The following is the code on .NET side:

```
int targetID = 2069;
int problemId1 = 0;
int tradeId1 = 0;

SqlParameter param1 = new SqlParameter("@targetType", 28);
SqlParameter param2 = new SqlParameter("@targeID", targetID);
SqlParameter param3 = new SqlParameter("@startDateToUse", "2019");
SqlParameter param4 = new SqlParameter("@problemID", problemId1);
SqlParameter param5 = new SqlParameter("@tradeID", tradeId1);

tempspexec = DbContext.Database
    .SqlQuery<StoredProcDataExecution>("exec GetWorkOrderChartDataAsync @targetType, @targeID, @startDateToUse, @problemID, @tradeID ", param1, param2, param3, param4, param5
    ).ToList();
```

***Note:*** Following screenshot shows param3 datatype and values for reference.

[image: Data Type Description]

## Explanation:

The Stored Procedure needs a String value for "startDateToUse" if we pass int to it, it crashes and returns all zero in Data-set. I am passing String in my .NET app but it still returns all zeros in my Dataset.

Following is what I see if I pass int value in SQLServer Query Editor.

[image: Deesc]

### Datatype changes to DateTime

[image: DateTime datatype]

Thank you for your support.

Comment: So what's the definition of `GetWorkOrderChartDataAsync`? In particular, what are its *actual*, declared parameter types, as opposed to the types inferred on the client side when you pass values?

Comment: all integer except "startDateToUse" that's a NVarChar in stored procedure side.

Comment: You asked this same question yesterday but deleted it this morning. Are you running this on the same database? I have to ask why is startDateToUse a string and not an int? Have you tried running profiler or extended events to truly see what values are being passed?

Comment: @SeanLange I'd want to ask why it isn't a `date`, but... sometimes a string is fine

Comment: @MarcGravell don't disagree about a date but it looks more like it is a year rather than a date. And if that is the case then it should be an int. Datatypes (and names) are important.

Comment: @SeanLange yes I had asked this question yesterday but someone closed the question making it unable to answer and my issue was not resolved.

Regarding datatype I agree with you, even if I pass "1/1/2019" in SQLServer the query runs and correct dataset is returned but if I do the same in my code it DOES NOT work. You can refer DbType and SqlDbType from above screenshot.

Comment: @Paras could you perhaps just *show the SP parameter definitions*? (in SQL, not C#) - this is very hard for us to diagnose in a vacuum - we can't run things to test it, etc - because we don't have the DB

Comment: @MarcGravell
`ALTER Proc [dbo].[GetWorkOrderChartDataAsync]
@targetType int = 28 
,@targeID int = 2069
,@startDateToUse datetime = '1/1/2019'
,@problemID int = 0
,@tradeID int = 0`

I know the startDateToUse is datetime datatype in SP but in Query Editor if I pass value "2019" it works there for me.

Comment: You should add details to the question, not comments. Are you 100% certain you are running this against the same database? I can't tell you how many times these types of bizarre sounding things end up being because the database isn't the same one.

Comment: @SeanLange I agree with you. I have double checked the database and it is correct.

Comment: Well then unless you can provide some details so others can test stuff there is nothing anybody can do to help you. We are guessing blind. We have no database, no procedure and we can't see your screen. Nobody can debug this in the dark.

Comment: @Paras so... after all that it *is* a `datetime`, not a `nvarchar`? if so: pass it as a `DateTime`!

Comment: @SeanLange I see your concern and you have a valid point. But due to security reasons I cannot disclose my database details, etc. on the internet. Is there any other way we can solve this?

Comment: @MarcGravell I did try that as well. 
` DateTime testYear = DateTime.UtcNow;
   SqlParameter param3 = new SqlParameter("@startDateToUse", testYear);
`
I am passing DateTime still dataset is zero. I can attach a screenshot what I see under the DbType and SqlDbType.

Comment: Understand security concerns, no problem there at all. The problem is we need to be able to reproduce a behavior so that a fix would correct it. And what you are describing doesn't make sense other than it being run against a different database. Try running profiler and see if the query is **really** being run where you think it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## I found a solution to this.

I started using SQLCommand instead of SQLQuery. Worked for time being.

```
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.
                                 ConnectionStrings["SampleTXT"].ConnectionString);
                    conn.Open();

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_GetWorkOrderChartDataAsync", conn);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (rdr.Read())
                    {
                       // Some Code here

                    }
                }
```

Thank you all for your crucial time and support. All the comments were so helpful.

Answer (score 0):

One failure reason I can see here is that the parameter order isn't what you think it is; in SSMS, you are passing the parameters by *name*, but in the C# you are passing them by *position*; perhaps try naming them in the `exec` usage?

```cs
tempspexec = DbContext.Database
    .SqlQuery<StoredProcDataExecution>("exec GetWorkOrderChartDataAsync @targetType=@targetType, @targeID=@targeID, @startDateToUse=@startDateToUse, @problemID=@problemID, @tradeID=@tradeID", param1, param2, param3, param4, param5
    ).ToList();
```

Note that it would be a lot cleaner if you could tell `SqlQuery` that you are invoking a stored procedure; then you don't need this at all, as "by name" is the default for SqlClient if the command-type is stored-procedure.

As an aside: you *might* find tools like Dapper easier for this:

```cs
tempspexec = conn.Query<StoredProcDataExecution>("GetWorkOrderChartDataAsync",
    new { // parameters
        targetType=28, targeID=targetID, startDateToUse="2019",
        problemID=problemId1, tradeID=tradeId1
    }, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).AsList();
```

Comment: I did try the method you mentioned (1st one). It did not work still zero in data-set.